# Which pin is pin #1?

Tags: integrated-circuit, pins

Where is pin #1 on this IC?

It seems to have a line and a dot. The dot doesn't seem to line up with a corner pin though.

Chip is a INA210AIDCKR.

[image]

Comment: While the datasheet does show a dot, I'm pretty sure the line is indicating that top left is pin 1. I will admit that that is a needlessly vague diagram in the datasheet however.

Comment: Great picture, well done

Comment: None of that looks like a real dot to me. The line at the top of the image, however, is definitely the thing you should pay attention to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally, **when the text/print is the correct way up, bottom-left is the pin-1.** This applies to QFP/LQFP, QFN, SOT, DIP, SOIC, SOP and maybe some other packages. For your question, it's the top-left according to the picture.

Comment: Oh really? Is this just your experience or is there an "official" norm/convention for this?

Comment: Have definitely seen some odd conventions before. No examples offhand unfortunately. Incidentally, PLCC does (or may?) start in the middle of a row, just to throw everyone off (good riddance I suppose?).

Comment: @tobalt sorry for the misunderstanding caused by my wording. Of course it's not an official thing, just like the fact that pin numbering direction is just a tradition.

Comment: @TimWilliams oh yeah, PLCC starts from the middle. I even forgot the existence of it, haven't seen one for years.

Answer (score 11):

In your picture, pin 1 should be top left. (I have never seen any ICs with a bar line that does not start on the first pin and ends on the last pin.)

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina213.pdf?ts=1706247841057) specifies pin 1 in relation to the index area:
[image]

Comment: +1. The "horizonal line" convention is extremely common in SOIC parts.

Answer (score 2):

I measured resistance between pins 1 and 4 (assuming top left is pin #1) and got a resistance of 1 or 2 MOhms (I can't remember now). Pins 3 to 6 were not connected. So this supports top left being pin #1.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a dot in the bottom right corner.

If it were my chip I would check VSS and VDD pins with a diode tester to be sure. Or you could try to measure the internal resistors.